# Visual Studio 2010 Crashing Upon Solution Load

Tags: windows-7, crash, visual-studio-2010, .net-framework

I recently installed Visual Studio 2010 Professional on my Windows 7 machine. When I did so, I had some problems with SQL Server Express 2008R2, so I uninstalled the version installed with VS2010 and installed it separately. However, after doing this (which took awhile - I didn't realize how hard it is to remove SQL Server completely from a machine), I fired up my solution (which opens up on other computers - all of which are running Windows XP and never had a problem with SQL Server Express) and, as the solution opens up, Visual Studio just crashes out.

I checked the event logs, but I don't understand what I can do to fix the problem. I did try to reinstall/repair Visual Studio, but that didn't seem to do anything. Any help in resolving this would be appreciated.

Here is an image of one of the warning/dialog boxes I get when loading Visual Studio (don't know if this pertains):

[image]

Here are the errors I get from my event logs after the crash (under Applications):

**VSTTExecution**

> The description for Event ID 0 from
>   source VSTTExecution cannot be found.
>   Either the component that raises this
>   event is not installed on your local
>   computer or the installation is
>   corrupted. You can install or repair
>   the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another
>   computer, the display information had
>   to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included
>   with the event:
>
> (devenv.exe, PID 6404, Thread 1)
>   TuipPackage.InitializeTestProjectPlugins:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could
>   not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestPackage,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified. File
>   name:
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestPackage,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String
>   name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean
>   ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark,
>   Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName,
>   ObjectHandleOnStack type)    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String
>   name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean
>   ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.GetType(String
>   typeName, Boolean throwOnError,
>   Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean
>   reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark)    at
>   System.Type.GetType(String typeName,
>   Boolean throwOnError, Boolean
>   ignoreCase)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Tips.TuipPackage.TuipPackage.InitializeTestProjectPlugins()
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is
>   turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry
>   value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]
>   (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some
>   performance penalty associated with
>   assembly bind failure logging. To turn
>   this feature off, remove the registry
>   value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> the message resource is present but
>   the message is not found in the
>   string/message table

**.NET Runtime**

> Application: devenv.exe Framework
>   Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
>   process was terminated due to an
>   unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException Stack:
>   at
>   Microsoft.Data.Schema.SchemaModel.ModelStore+SqlCeManager.Dispose(Boolean,
>   System.String)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Schema.SchemaModel.ModelStore+SqlCeManager.Finalize()

Comment: I experienced a similar problem after I added a 10MB HTML file to my solution. Upon reload the solution it would crash like above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the solution file was corrupted. I rolled back my solution file, made the changes I had previously made, and everything has been fine since that point.